# Can't start dockerized event store with all projections running

Tags: docker, eventstoredb

I'm trying to run event store using docker in windows, but for some reason, my projections start stopped.

Here is what I'm executing

```
docker run --name eventstore-node -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 --run-projections=ALL --start-standard-projections=TRUEeventstore/eventstore
```

Also tried running as environment variables

```
docker run --name eventstore-node -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 -e EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=ALL -e EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS=TRUE eventstore/eventstore
```

This is how my projections are shown after running the docker container
[docker administrator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENjXu.png)

Does anyone had a clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

The commands:

```
docker run --name eventstore-node -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 eventstore/eventstore --run-projections=ALL --start-standard-projections=TRUE

docker run --name eventstore-node -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 eventstore/eventstore -e EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=ALL -e EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS=TRUE
```

are both not the right shape.

See the documentation for the docker image.

https://hub.docker.com/r/eventstore/eventstore/

Example:

```
docker run -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 -e EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=ALL eventstore/eventstore
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realize it after posting, I will correct my question. The correct command is not working too... Projections are shown as stopped

Comment: the command in my answer is just an exmaple of the correct way , not the complete command with all the options you may need, you need to explore all the options and then pass them via -e

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason, the ALL word, should be written like this "All" not capital L's. Now its working for me. 
Thanks